# How to skip an empty <td> using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a loop iterating over a html table to get the data of each row. From time to time some table-cells (td) in a table-row might be empty or only include a `<br>` tag. I am now trying to get some logic to skip them or assign a value of `null` to the variables in such cases.

- I am not really sure if a `<td> <br> </td>` element is considered as an empty text or if the `<br>` is considered as string in that case
- Additonally, the amount of spaces between `<td> .... <br> .. </td>` might vary from situation to situation (if that matters).

This is where the error occurs:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q39VL.jpg)

This is the (common) html table structure:

```
<table>
  <thead> [...] </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr> [...] </tr>
    <tr> [...] </tr>
    <tr> [...] </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 23,77<br>44,11 </td> // works just fine
      <td><br></td>   // error throws here, since no data/strings, only <br> included
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**My first attempt**

```
prices = td_list[1].text
if not td_list[1].text.strip():
    prices = td_list[1].text.strip().split("\r\n")
    priceA = prices[0]
    priceB = prices[1]
else:
    priceA = ''
    priceB = ''
```

which throws me `IndexError: list index out of range` what suggests that the logic test does not work and the loop does not skip to `else` although the text inside `td_list[1]` is not existent.

**My second attempt**

```
prices = td_list[1].text
if prices == '<br>':
    prices = td_list[1].text.strip().split("\r\n")
    priceA = prices[0]
    priceB = prices[1]
else:
    priceA = ''
    priceB = ''
```

which then skips this element in every iteration of the loop.. no matter if there are some additional strings or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for empty table rows like this :

```
prices= BS(html)
for table in prices.findAll("table" ,text=None,recursive=True):
    if table.text:
        print table["id"]
```

Hope you get the idea !

Comment: Ah you provided me with the piece I was missing. I tried `if td_list[1].text == None` which works just fine. Thanks!